# VBA macros - export CSV file format and extension don't match

Tags: vba, excel, csv, outlook

I'm using this code to export Outlook data (emails) to CSV file:

```
Sub ExportMessagesToExcel()
Dim olkMsg As Object, _
    excApp As Object, _
    excWkb As Object, _
    excWks As Object, _
    intRow As Integer, _
    intVersion As Integer, _
    strFilename As String
'strFilename = InputBox("Enter a filename (including path) to save the exported messages to.", "Export Messages to Excel")
strFilename = "C:...\...\Emails.csv"
If strFilename <> "" Then
    intVersion = GetOutlookVersion()
    Set excApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set excWkb = excApp.Workbooks.Add()
    Set excWks = excWkb.ActiveSheet
    'Write Excel Column Headers
    With excWks
        .Cells(1, 1) = "Subject"
        .Cells(1, 2) = "Received"
        .Cells(1, 3) = "Sender"
    End With
    intRow = 2
    'Write messages to spreadsheet
    For Each olkMsg In Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items
        'Only export messages, not receipts or appointment requests, etc.
        If olkMsg.Class = olMail Then
            'Add a row for each field in the message you want to export
            excWks.Cells(intRow, 1) = olkMsg.Subject
            excWks.Cells(intRow, 2) = olkMsg.ReceivedTime
            excWks.Cells(intRow, 3) = olkMsg.SenderName
            intRow = intRow + 1
        End If
    Next
    Set olkMsg = Nothing
    excWkb.SaveAs strFilename
    excWkb.Close
End If
Set excWks = Nothing
Set excWkb = Nothing
Set excApp = Nothing
MsgBox "Process complete.  A total of " & intRow - 2 & " messages were exported.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Export messages to Excel"
End Sub

Private Function GetSMTPAddress(Item As Outlook.MailItem, intOutlookVersion As Integer) As String
Dim olkSnd As Outlook.AddressEntry, olkEnt As Object
On Error Resume Next
Select Case intOutlookVersion
    Case Is < 14
        If Item.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
            GetSMTPAddress = SMTP2007(Item)
        Else
            GetSMTPAddress = Item.SenderEmailAddress
        End If
    Case Else
        Set olkSnd = Item.Sender
        If olkSnd.AddressEntryUserType = olExchangeUserAddressEntry Then
            Set olkEnt = olkSnd.GetExchangeUser
            GetSMTPAddress = olkEnt.PrimarySmtpAddress
        Else
            GetSMTPAddress = Item.SenderEmailAddress
        End If
End Select
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set olkPrp = Nothing
    Set olkSnd = Nothing
    Set olkEnt = Nothing
End Function

Function GetOutlookVersion() As Integer
    Dim arrVer As Variant
    arrVer = Split(Outlook.Version, ".")
    GetOutlookVersion = arrVer(0)
End Function

Function SMTP2007(olkMsg As Outlook.MailItem) As String
    Dim olkPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olkPA = olkMsg.PropertyAccessor
    SMTP2007 = olkPA.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D01001E")
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set olkPA = Nothing
End Function
```

But when I open the downloaded file, Excel says the file format and extension don't match.

What could cause this issue?

Comment: The error is because you are saving an EXCEL file (as an Excel file), but you are naming it as a 'CSV'. If you name it as '.XLS' it will work, or if you change your code to save as CSV...

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
"c:\MyFile.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV _
, CreateBackup:=False

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn Is it a new string I need to add to my code? If "yes" where about should I include it?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn Ijust tried to change extention to '.XLS' and open that file but this have the same issue!

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn I want it to in CSV

Comment: What version of Excel do you have? To save as an Excel file, change the extension to '.xlsx'. Otherwise look at the parameter for file type i.e.: 'FileFormat:=xlCSV'

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn I've got this erros now: Run-time error '1004' SaveAs method of Workbook class failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your two lines from:

```
excWkb.SaveAs strFilename
excWkb.Close
```

to:

```
excWkb.SaveAs Filename:=strFilename, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
excWkb.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me and not giving up but I've got this erros now: Run-time error '1004' SaveAs method of Workbook class failed

Comment: Where are you running this VBA code? Possibly you have not included a reference to the Excel library?  Try changing the SaveAs to: 
excWkb.SaveAs Filename:=strFilename, FileFormat:=6, CreateBackup:=False

Comment: I just try - excWkb.SaveAs Filename:=strFilename, FileFormat:=6, CreateBackup:=False. Sorted, nice one! ;)